# Matplotlib Animation not completing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've tried to create an animation using Matplotlib, it seems to be animating correctly but it's not showing all the data points in the dataset. Its a time series from Jan 2020 to Dec 2021 - it seems to be animating to 2020-06 only right now.

Below is the entire code

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Get data
data = yf.download('TSLA',start='2020-01-01')
df = data['Adj Close'].to_frame()

fig = plt.figure() 
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')

def buildchart(i=int):
        plt.legend(df.columns)
        p = plt.plot(df[:i].index, df[:i].values, color = 'black')

import matplotlib.animation as ani
animator = ani.FuncAnimation(fig, buildchart, interval = 100)

import os
f = os.getcwd() + '/animation.mp4'
writervideo = ani.FFMpegWriter(fps=30) 
animator.save(f, writer=writervideo, dpi= 300)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic form of the animation is to set the empty graph type and the x-axis and y-axis ranges, and then update the data with the animation function. It is rewritten in an object-oriented way because it is easy to set up the details. The animation is set to repeat for a number of records in a number of frames.

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Get data
data = yf.download('TSLA',start='2020-01-01')
df = data['Adj Close'].to_frame()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [], color='k', lw=3)
ax.set(xlim=(df.index[0], df.index[-1]), ylim=(df['Adj Close'].min(), df['Adj Close'].max()))
ax.set_ylabel('Stock Price')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')

def buildchart(i):
    line.set_data(df[:i].index, df[:i]['Adj Close'])

ax.legend(df.columns)

anim = ani.FuncAnimation(fig, buildchart, frames=len(df), interval=100)

plt.show()
```